# Theano - Sum by group

Tags: python, theano

I'm working on a custom likelihood function for Theano (Attempting to fit a conditional logistic regression.)

The likelihood requires summing values ***by group***.  In R we have the "ave()" function, in Python Pandas we have "groupby()".  How would I do something similar in Theano?

**Edited for more detail**

I want to create a cox proportional hazards model (same as conditional logistic regression.)  The log likelihood requires the sum of values by group:

[image: \sum{_{g=1}^G]

In Pandas, this would be:

```
temp = df.groupby('groupid')['eta'].aggregate(np.sum)
denominator = np.log(temp).sum()
```

In the data, we have a column with group ID, and the values to be summed

```
group    eta
1        2.1
1        1.8
1        0.9
2        1.2
2        0.75
2        1.42
```

The output for the group sums would then be:

```
group    sum
1        4.8
2        3.37
```

Then, the sum of the log of the sums:

```
log(4.8) + log(3.37) = 2.7835
```

This is quick and easy to do in Pandas.  How can I do something similar in Thano?  Sure, could write a nexted loop, but that seems slow and I try to avoid manually coded loops when possible as they are slow.

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately there is no groupby function in theano. If you could give some details as to exactly what you are trying to accomplish (maybe a bit of example code) you will get better help.

Comment: Another thought was to do something clever with matrix multiplication.  Perhaps a matrix of group indicator values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let say you have "X" (a list of all your etas), with the dim. Nx1 (I guess) and a matrix H. H is a NxG matrix that has a on-hot encoding of the groups.

The you you write something like:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import newaxis as na
import theano.tensor as T

X = T.vector()
H = T.matrix()

tmp = T.sum(X[:, na] * H, axis=0)
O = T.sum(T.log(tmp))

x = np.array([5, 10, 10, 0.5, 5, 0.5])
# create a 1-hot encoding
g = np.array([1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0])
h = np.zeros(shape=(len(x), 3))
for i,j in enumerate(g):
    h[i,j] = 1.0

O.eval({X:x, H: h})
```

This should work as long as there is at least one eta per point (or else -inf).